# A code to destroy the value of a variable in livecode

Tags: livecode

I have a question , I noticed that when I use a variable to count the score of clicks of different objects . The value of the score that uses variable whether it was a global or a local variable maintain its value of the score that has reached and continues to count from that point even when I close and re-open the app and I reset the variable value to 0 with code (put 0 into _gScorePlayer ) for example when a user reaches score 15 and closes the app , next time the score continues from 15 and so on

I am a beginner in livecode
Thanks fro your continues help and support guys :)

Comment: have you tried initializing the count variable to zero before the program starts??. I believe that if you set its initial value to zero, the program will always refer to that whenever it starts!

Comment: how to do  what you just wrote ?

Comment: How about you share the codes where you have declared that count variable so that I can refer to it?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the put command to clear the variable and the delete command to remove it from memory.
check the LiveCode dictionary
delete variable

Example

```
delete local tVar [1]
```

Comment: This is,by far, the best answer up to now. I would add that you can do this for variables, both regular variables and arrays. The index [1] would only delete that particular element from an array, while without index it would delete the entire variable.

Answer (score 1):

By default, declaring variables is optional in LiveCode.* Persistence of variable values is determined by whether the variable is declared outside of a handler or not. When a variable is only declared or used inside a handler, the variable is *always* temporary and its value is only valid while the handler is running.

The value of variables declared as `local` or `global` *outside of a handler* will persist between instances of the handler being run. However, the value of such variables will not persist between launches of LiveCode. That is if you *quit* LiveCode and launch it again, the values of the declared variables will be lost. However, if you only *close the stack* without quitting LiveCode, the stack remains in memory (by default) and the values of declared variables remain intact.

If you want to ensure that the variable is reset when the stack is reopened, do this for declared globals in the stack script:

```
global gScorePlayer

on openStack
   put empty into gScorePlayer
   # OR
   put 0 into gScorePlayer
end open stack
```

To initialize `local` variables you do something similar in the script where the variable is used. For example, if you are using a `local` variable in a card script, you can do this in the card script:

```
local sMyLocalVar

on openCard
   put empty into sMyLocalVar # or put 0 into sMyLocalVar
end openCard
```

> *See the `explicitVariables` property in the Dictionary for more information about declaring variables.

Answer (score 0):

The way I use to clean the content of a variable is:

```
delete variable VariableName
```